# CSS files missing when deploying to Azure (datepicker style works locally)

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, azure, datepicker

I deployed a MVC 5 Web App to Azure and saw that the datepicker theme (basic) is not loading properly.

Local datepicker:

[image: Local datepicker]

Azure datepicker:

[image: Azure datepicker]

From digging through the Azure version, I observed that the stylesheets aren't loading, although locally they are. Clearly this is the issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                  "~/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/base/all.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

....

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

**UPDATE:** 
Inspecting the field in which the datepicker should appear, I found that this is a minification issue:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(31,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@import'
(31,9): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '"base.css"'
(32,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@import'
(32,9): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '"theme.css"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding the error (Inspect element on the Datepicker Field in the Azure-deployed Web App):

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(31,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@import'
(31,9): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '"base.css"'
(32,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@import'
(32,9): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '"theme.css"'
```

I modified BundleConfig.cs by including manually all the css files that all.css was importing:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    // Code removed for clarity

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/core.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/base.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/theme.css",
              "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this!
Have you included the files in your project?
Click the all files button and then you might have to add the files if they aren't included

Comment: No sorry in visual studio, switch to solution explorer and then at the top there is a button to view all files, it near the refresh button. Find the files, right click add files

Comment: I published those files specificlly, but no change :(

Comment: Mmm, well I did tell a little fib here when this happened to me I used web publish but I guess it's similar to azure. Anyway I'd have a look in azure (presume you can browse) are the files there? I know that c# minifies the files and combines them together when published, check the files maybe that didn't happen properly. When publishing you can check the differences, maybe do that. Other - Clear browser cache, check browser for javascript errors. Check differences between local script and azure. There is a jquery-ui.css for example, don't you need that with this picker?

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. Was on holiday and didn't get around to open a laptop. I've explored the files that were published on azure and they are all there. Don't understand why they are not used. jquery-ui-1.11.4.js is here aswell

Comment: mmm, All the files are there, but no display...... Sorry I'm out. Go back to basics - Javascript errors, check the images are there. Is it a mode thing debug/release? I'm sorry but I really don't have an answer. Have to say that in the past when this has happened to me it's down to the files not being there so I would check again. Perhaps you css files are referencing other files that aren't included in your project. So are there locally but not on azure. do a search in your css files for "@import url". Might give you something

Comment: Thanks for trying :)

Comment: Ooo, just thought is there an issue with the file and the azure iis. So it's not being supplied to the browser as a css file. In this case perhaps open edit, republish might help. Sorry it's a bit tricky and all I can do is put ideas out there.

Comment: Tried, but as before, it didn't work. I'll start searching some more. Apparently this problem doesn't appear that often, as in I cannot find others that had this. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: No probs - like you say this feels like a azure specific problem. Not a 'publish' issue. As you are (I think) paying for azure - perhaps microsoft could help.?

Comment: Unfortunatly you have to pay a support plan in order to get support from them. I do pay for the Azure SQL Database but not for the web app service.